# Select values in loop by tag

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of values:

```
<?php

$array_values=array("image.png","image_min.png","image_med.png","image_max.png");

for ($i=0; $i<count($array_values); $i++)
{    
    print "".$array_values[$i]."";    
}

?>
```

How can I show only the files with the tag _min and not the rest of the values?

Comment: does it have to be inside the for loop? Does you data always look like that? Are you aware of how to access an array ($array_values[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php    
$array_values=array("image.png","image_min.png","image_med.png","image_max.png");

foreach ($array_values as $value)
{    
    if (strpos($value, "_min") !== FALSE) {
        print "".$value."";
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Why "". ?? It makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition, so that the `print` statement is only called when a certain condition is met. Try this:

```
<?php
$array_values = array("image.png", "image_min.png", "image_med.png", "image_max.png");
for ($i=0; $i<count($array_values); $i++)
    if (strpos($array_values[$i], "_min") !== false)
        print $array_values[$i];
```

Comment: why "". ? it makes no sense

Comment: @RonniSkansing, good point, removed it. I initially copied it from the question.

Comment: Not best performance case because count() function called each iteration. It's OK for small arrays but what about big arrays?

Comment: @romik, I know this can be done more efficient, but I was just keeping the code as close to the code of the OP as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For php 5.3+ you can using closures:

```
$values = array_filter($array_values, function($item) {
    return false !== strpos($item, "_min");
});
```

Comment: Nice. OP beware this returns an array.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you get more detailed comment?